# create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts gets Jest 20.0

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

When I start a brand-new CRA typescript project, I seem to get stuck with an ancient version of Jest:

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
cd my-app

yarn test -v
v20.0.4
```

... but the same thing for a javascript project (e.g. without `--scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`) gets Jest 23 (the latest as of this writing).

1) what might I be doing wrong?

2) is there something I can do later to get a correctly-configured jest 23 for typescript?

Comment: this helps when added to package.json, but why necessary? "resolutions": {
    "react-scripts-ts/jest": "^23"
  },